# Sublime regex only finds one match per file

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to use the following regexp find/replace in Sublime Text to convert a commonjs module require into a es6 module import statement.

find:

```
var (\w+) = require\('(\w+)'\)\;
```

replace

```
import $1 from '$2';
```

Somehow it only finds one match per file, and only on the first line. What do I have to change to make it match in the whole file? I've tried adding a /g for global but without luck.

Here's some example text.

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
```

If I use find (cmd-F) it only finds the first occurrence regardless if I press find / find prev / find all.

Comment: did you click the replaceAll button?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes I think I've clicked every button that was somewhat sensible

Comment: i think you clicked the replace button instead of replaceAll button.

Comment: No, I've tried that, no difference. Can you confirm it works for you in ST3?

Comment: Perhaps your RegEx is inadequate for the text you're searching. Can you provide a sample of the actual text you're searching?

Comment: Also, is this Sublime Text 2 or 3?

Comment: I've added the example. I'm using ST3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var (\w+) = require\('(\w+)'\)\;
```

here `\w` means any **word character**.
But your second line

```
var Router = require('react-router');
```

has also a **dash** which is no word character I guess.

Use the following regex to recognize the dash too.

```
var (\w+) = require\('([\w\-]+)'\)\;
```

Comment: This is the correct diagnosis, but I would prescribe a more versatile Regular Expression that performs a non-greedy match on all characters between the parentheses: `var (\w+) = require\('(.+?)'\)\;` Alternatively, you could look for non-whitespace characters: `var (\w+) = require\('(\S+?)'\)\;` Or define a set of restricted characters to NOT match: `var (\w+) = require\('([^\/:*?"<>|]+?)'\)\;`

Comment: Yes that was it! Thanks. I also needed the . and \ in there so eventually I used ```var (\w+) = require\('([\w\-.\/]+)'\)\;```

Comment: @gfullam Thanks I only read you comment just now, but it's good to know the alternative :)